# How to check if all the pre-requisites required for MPI to run has been applied?

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, intel-mpi, intel-cluster-checker

How to check if all the pre-requisites required for MPI to run has been applied? I want to verify whether the cluster is configured as expected or not.

Comment: If you can eat you own dog food, try Intel Cluster Checker https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/cluster-checker.html :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cluster Checker tool provided by Intel.

Link: [https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/cluster-checker.html]

```
clck -f ./<nodefile> -F mpi_prereq_user
```

The above code will run diagnostic checks related to Intel® MPI Library functionality and help verify that the cluster is configured as expected.

Comment: if this is an infomercial, you should clearly state it. And if Intel Cluster Checker only supports Intel MPI, that should also be made crystal clear.